# Find value in multidimensional array based on key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, find

I have an array with multiple array, and in each array one of the fields is another array, see below. I need to find the value for "First name", in the array that has an 'item_id' of value 177. How can I do that?

```
array(1) { 
[0]=> array(4) 
{ 
["product_id"]=> int(62) 
["item_id"]=> int(177) 
["quantity"]=> int(1) 
["options"]=> array(5) { 
[0]=> array(4) { 
["field_id"]=> string(13) "655259ef26f01" 
["label"]=> string(11) "First name:" 
["value"]=> string(4) "test" ["type"]=> string(4) "text" } 
[1]=> array(4) { ["field_id"]=> string(13) "65525a47553c3" 
["label"]=> string(10) "Last name:" 
["value"]=> string(4) "test" ["type"]=> string(4) "text" } 
[2]=> array(4) { 
["field_id"]=> string(13) "65525a658669b" 
["label"]=> string(15) "E-mail address:" 
["value"]=> string(17) "sample@mail.com" 
["type"]=> string(5) "email" } 
[3]=> array(4) { ["field_id"]=> string(13) "65525a964be34" 
["label"]=> string(27) "Language for questionnaire:" 
["value"]=> string(6) "German" 
["type"]=> string(6) "select" }
} } 

[1]=> array(4) { 
["product_id"]=> int(62) 
["item_id"]=> int(182) 
["quantity"]=> int(1) 
["options"]=> array(7) { 
[0]=> array(4) { 
["field_id"]=> string(13) "655259ef26f01" 
["label"]=> string(11) "First name:" 
["value"]=> string(4) "test" 
["type"]=> string(4) "text" 
} 
[1]=> array(4) { 
["field_id"]=> string(13) "65525a47553c3" 
["label"]=> string(10) "Last name:" 
["value"]=> string(4) "test" 
["type"]=> string(4) "text" 
} 
[2]=> array(4) { 
["field_id"]=> string(13) "65525a658669b" 
["label"]=> string(15) "E-mail address:" 
["value"]=> string(17) "sample@mail.com" 
["type"]=> string(5) "email" 
} 
[3]=> array(4) { 
["field_id"]=> string(13) "65525a7bb053f" 
["label"]=> string(46) "Send copy of the report to this email address:" 
["value"]=> string(17) "sample@mail.com" 
["type"]=> string(5) "email" 
} 
[4]=> array(4) { 
["field_id"]=> string(13) "65525a964be34" 
["label"]=> string(27) "Language for questionnaire:" 
["value"]=> string(7) "Chinese" ["type"]=> string(6) "select" }
} } }
```

I have tried several things, one of them this:

```
$fname = $customs['item_id'][$itemID]['options']['field_id']['655259ef26f01']['value'];
```

Comment: Do you just need this one field one time or do you fetch other values from this data?

Comment: I fetch other fields too

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function that searches through the `$custom` array, then if the `item_id` matches what is passed, look through the `options` sub-array and then pluck out the `value` when `field_id` matches:

```
<?php

/*

Question Author: Pete
Question Answerer: Jacob Mulquin
Question: Find value in multidimensional array based on key
URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77506541/find-value-in-multidimensional-array-based-on-key
Tags: , php, multidimensional-array, find

*/

$customs = [
    [
        'product_id' => 61,
        'item_id' => 177,
        'quantity' => 1,
        'options' => [
            [
                'field_id' => '655259ef26f01',
                'label' => 'First name:',
                'value' => 'test firstname1',
                'type' => 'text'
            ],
            [
                'field_id' => '65525a47553c3',
                'label' => 'Last name:',
                'value' => 'test lastname1',
                'type' => 'text'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'product_id' => 60,
        'item_id' => 177,
        'quantity' => 1,
        'options' => [
            [
                'field_id' => '655259ef26f01',
                'label' => 'First name:',
                'value' => 'test firstname1 again',
                'type' => 'text'
            ],
            [
                'field_id' => '65525a47553c3',
                'label' => 'Last name:',
                'value' => 'test lastname1',
                'type' => 'text'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'product_id' => 62,
        'item_id' => 182,
        'quantity' => 1,
        'options' => [
            [
                'field_id' => '655259ef26f01',
                'label' => 'First name:',
                'value' => 'test firstname2',
                'type' => 'text'
            ],
            [
                'field_id' => '65525a47553c3',
                'label' => 'Last name:',
                'value' => 'test lastname2',
                'type' => 'text'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

function search_item_array($search, $item_id, $field_id)
{
    $found = [];
    foreach ($search as $record) {
        if ($record['item_id'] !== $item_id)
            continue;

        foreach ($record['options'] as $option) {
            if ($option['field_id'] === $field_id)
                $found[] = $option['value'];
        }
    }
    return $found;
}

$output = search_item_array($customs, 177, '655259ef26f01');
var_dump($output);
```

Yields:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "test firstname1"
  [1]=>
  string(21) "test firstname1 again"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want one field, the using `foreach` makes sense. If you are going to fetch several field values it can help to convert your fields array into an indexed array with the field_id as the index.  This can easily be done using `array_column()`

So something like

```
foreach ($customs as $product) {
    if ($product['item_id'] == 177) {
        // Index the options by the field_id column.
        $product['options'] = array_column($product['options'], null, 'field_id');

        echo $product['options']['655259ef26f01']['value'] . PHP_EOL; // first name
        echo $product['options']['65525a47553c3']['value'] . PHP_EOL; // last_name
    }
}
```

If you use this data on a regular basis, it may be useful to create the original data with some useful index (perhaps having product_id at the top level and field_id for the options) to help in fetching the values.